# While parameter routing in angular 2, constructor injection prevents the page from loading

Tags: angular

`emp-list.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
       selector:'emp-list',
       template:`
                <ul>
                    <li (click)="onSelect(emp)"  *ngFor="let emp of employees">
                       <span> {{emp.id}}</span>----<span>{{emp.name}}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
       `
})


export class  EmployeeListComponent 
{
    constructor(private router:Router) { }

    employees = [
        {"id":12,"name":"Srikant"},
        {"id":13,"name":"Sriram"},
        {"id":14,"name":"Sushant"}
    ]      
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  template: ` 
             <emp-list></emp-list>
  `   
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {EmployeeListComponent} from './Employees/emp-list.component';
import { EmployeeParticularComponent } from './Employees/emp-details.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule,

  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent,EmployeeListComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 


}

When removing the constructor, everything works fine.
```

Comment: any error messages in the console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

`Router` is defined in the `RouterModule`, but you did not import it in your `app.module.ts`.

You should get the following error in the console:

> Error: StaticInjectorError[Router]:    StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

Add it to your imports list.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: "", component: AppComponent}])
   ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See my working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-49014646) example. The constructor with the `router` parameter is in the `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector:'app-root',
    template:`
           <h1>Hello World</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{

   // constructor(private router:Router){}

}

Comment: When uncommenting constructor(private router:Router){}, the "Hello World" is not shown.